# Association rule mining basics - How to read association rules

Tags: associations, weka, data-mining

A very basic question here:

Example rule (suppose its generated from WEKA) :

```
bread=t 10 ==> milk=t 10 conf:(1)
```

Which means that "from 10 instances, everytime people buy bread, they also buy milk". (ignore the support)

Does this rule can be read both ways? Like, "every time people buy milk, they also buy bread?"

Another example

```
Physics101=A ==> Superphysics401=A
```

Can it be read both ways like this:

"If people got A on Physics101, they also got A on Superphysics401"

"If people got A on Superphysics401, they also got A on Physics101" ?

If so, what makes WEKA generate the rule in that order (Physics ==> Superphysics), why not the other way? Or does the order not relevant?

Answer (score 3):

`Does this rule can be read both ways? Like, "everytime people buy milk, they also buy bread?"`

**No,** it can only be read one way.

This follows from the rules of implication. `A -> B` and `B -> A` are different things. Read former as "A is a subset of B", thus, whenever you are in A, you are in B. `B -> A`, also called converse of `A -> B`, can be interpreted in similar way. When both of these hold, we say that `A <-> B` which means that `A` and `B` are essentially the same.

If the above looks like too much jargon, keep the following in mind:
Rain -> Clouds is true. Whenever there is rain, there will be clouds, But Clouds -> Rain is not always true. There may be clouds but no rain.

> If so, what makes WEKA generate the rule in that order (Physics ==>
>   Superphysics), why not the other way? Or does the order not relevant?

The dataset leads to the rules. Here is an example :

```
Milk, Bread, Waffers
Milk, Toasts, Butter
Milk, Bread, Cookies
Milk, Cashewnuts
```

Convince yourself that Bread -> Milk, but Milk ! -> Bread.

Note that we may not be always interested in rules that either hold or do not hold. Thus, we try to add a notion of confidence to the rules. A natural way of defining confidence for `A->B` is `P(B|A)` i.e. how often do we see B when we see A.
This can be calculated by dividing the count of B and A appearing together and dividing by the count of A appearing alone.

In our example,

```
        P(Milk | Bread) = 2 / 2  = 1 and
        P(Bread | Milk) = 2 / 4 = 0.5
```

You can now sort list of rules on the basis of confidence and decide which ones do you want to use.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. But Im still curious. From that example, we can say that Milk -> Bread with 50% confidence, 50% of the time, when people buy bread, they buy milk. But we can also see it as, Bread -> Milk with 100% confidence right? 100% of the time, when people buy bread, they will buy milk. Is this not right?

Comment: @soryuken Yes, they are both rules, with different levels of confidence. See my edit for more.

Comment: is there any association miner java library for strings, help is really appreciated